# In "Fear Itself," did Matt Fraction base his additions to the Thor-canon on actual Norse mythology?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel

In the current mini-series event "Fear Itself," Matt Fraction introduces a character known as the Serpent who is Odin's brother claims that Odin usurped the throne of Asgard from him. He also has a group of 8 followers, all of whom have mythological-sounding names. They are:

- Skadi: Herald of the "Serpent"
- Kuurth: Breaker of Stone
- Nul: Breaker of Worlds
- Skirn: Breaker of Men
- Nerkkod: Breaker of Oceans
- Mokk: Breaker of Faith
- Greithoth: Breaker of Wills
- Angir: Breaker of Souls

Do any of these characters have a basis in Norse mythology, or did Fraction string together a bunch of consonants to form all of these new names and characters?

Comment: Some of these names are misspellings of appropriate English words: "Nul" = null, "Mokk" = mock, "Angir" = anger.

Comment: I think you should be able to find this easily on the internet if you do a bit of research on things like Asgard, or take Odin as starting point on Wikipedia and see the related entries. Germanic mythology is the field of expertise these gods/beings fall under. See also: http://www.viking-mythology.com/ I downvoted because I think this is a bit of a lazy question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skadi at least was a "real" Norse goddess, who was the daughter of a giant.

[See this.](http://meadhall.homestead.com/Skadipage.html)

Comment: That's also the only one of the names that shows up in the Norse index in [Encyclopedia Mythica](http://www.pantheon.org/areas/mythology/europe/norse/articles.html), so I'm inclined to believe he made the rest of them up.

Answer (score 5):

In norse mythology, During Ragnarok Thor fights the Migard serpent. They kill each other in the battle. Hence why the main villain is the Serpent and Thor says he must fight him alone.
Skadi is a real norse goddess, the rest are made up, but the names sound cool